# Communication between non related components with EventEmitter

Tags: angular, rxjs

The EventEmitter is not working and I dont get any errors so I do not know where the problem is.

My Service:

```
public newRecommendEmitter:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

addNewRecommendation(purchaseRecommend):Observable<any>{ 
  debugger;
  let url = this.baseUrl + "component/newPurchaseRecommend";
  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(purchaseRecommend), this.options).pipe(map((data)=>{
    this.newRecommendEmitter.emit(data); // This is where I emit the new Data.
  }))
 
}
```

My First Component which send the data:

sendRecommandation() {

```
  this.recommandPurchase.user = this.authService.loggedInUser.userName;

  // here is where I send the data to the service , I emit the new data in that service as you can see above.
  this.inventoryService.addNewRecommendation(this.recommandPurchase).subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.toastSrv.success("New Recommendation Added")

    }
  })
```

}

My Second Component which should get the data:

```
 ngOnInit() {

   this.inventoryService.newRecommendEmitter.subscribe(data=>{
     debugger;
      this.purchaseRecommendations.push(data)
    })
  }
```

Any idea where I went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

[`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L95) is an Angular specific extension of RxJS [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) multicast observable. `Subject`s will only emit the notifications that were emitted *after* the subscription. In your case probably the emission is before the subscription.

You could look into RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 instead. It will buffer the latest emission and emit it to future observers immediately upon subscription.

Moreover the RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator is used to transform the emitted value from the observable. You could use [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) instead to perform side-effects.

Try the following

```js
public newRecommendEmitter: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

addNewRecommendation(purchaseRecommend):Observable<any>{ 
  debugger;
  let url = this.baseUrl + "component/newPurchaseRecommend";
  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(purchaseRecommend), this.options).pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      this.newRecommendEmitter.next(data); // Use `next` here
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: So where do I emit the newRecommend if I only use next and subscribe ?

Comment: `next()` is the emission. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L104). The `emit` function is a plain wrapper for the `next()` function.

Comment: I see, it's still not working without any errors. I think the emission worked but the component which subscribed is not getting the data

Comment: Maybe the subscription should not be in ngOnInIt ?

Comment: No there isn't any issue in the subscription inside `ngOnInit`. How are you saying the component is not getting the data? Did you do a `console.log` inside the subscription?

Comment: I did console.log and I also placed a debugger to see if it stops there. it didn't stop there or console.log any value

Comment: It doesn't really make sense then. Check if the value is actually emitted inside the `tap` operator.

Comment: Do I need to use @Output propery inside the service ? because right now my emitter is declared with Public and thats it

Comment: No `@Output` is to be used in a child component when it wishes to emit a value to it's parent component using the `EventEmitter`.

Comment: This is not about child and parent components , I wrote that those components are not related

Comment: That's what I said too. I was explaining in which situation you'd need the `@Output`. You do not need it here.

Comment: oh alright , so no idea what it isn't working